# How to interrupt page unload from javascript without confirm or return

Tags: javascript

Problemm is: I have form that has changed data in it and on onbeforeunload event i bind form validation and warning message about unsaved data. Erlier i've used return/confirm function, so user has seen browser modal window with two buttons Ok and Cancel. As this case difficult to test I decided to do over confirm process whithout using those two functions.

How can I interrupt page unload inside onbeforeunload event without using confirm/return functions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way to prevent page unload other then using `onbeforeunload` event - if there was google would probably have used it in gmail - but they didn't.

If you'd try to do it with `unload` event you can at best force the user to stay on the same page - page will reload though and most likely you'll loose all your data.

Comment: Tom, i meant how to do it inside `onbeforeunload` but without `confirm` and `return` functions. Is there another way to grub user confirmation?

Comment: The popup that onbeforeunload is a system element which is browser specific - there is no way to style it or to change the system messages aparto of the text you return in the onbeforeunload function. Keep in mind that these system messages are also influenced by browser locale so if somebody have browser in German, Dutch, Polish or whatever they can see some messy mixture of different languages which is terrible. But you can't do anything about it it's done this way for security reasons - and in web security goes first.

Comment: would rather help you with positive answer but oh well :) good luck out there!